# Creating a dynamic range in VBA from unique texts in reference file and looping into dashboard

Tags: vba, excel, loops, dynamic, reference

[image]

I have code here that takes data from a reference file and counts all of the unique text lines and places them in a list of their own in the reference file. It is then supposed to place each of the unique texts into columns shown in this picture if "Title" is in column 4. Right now though, it just takes the first unique line from the reference file "title1" and loops it into every box. What I want is the rest of the unique texts to loop through as well. So, it will be "title1", "title2", "title3", etc. I can't quite figure it out though.

```
Sub unique()

    Dim wsRef As Worksheet
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet

    Set wsRef = Worksheets("reference1")
    Set wsDB = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wsRef
        .Range("F1:F60").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("I1"), unique:=True

        Dim arrValues As Variant
        arrValues = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    End With

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        If Cells(i, 4) = "Title" Then

            For j = 1 To (UBound(arrValues)) Step 1

                With wsDB
                .Range(.Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), .Cells(i, j * 4 + 4)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrValues)

                End With

            Next j

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: replace `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrValues)` with `arrValues(j)` ... see if it helps :)

Comment: When you are talking about files, do you really mean that you have to loop trough excel files?

Comment: @bennogrimm no looping within the dashboard to place unique lines of text in each column header from a reference file

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the data?

Comment: @thomasinzina added a picture to the bottom..it's very vague but basically it takes the data on the left and copies it to the right with only unique values

Comment: @ScottHoltzman object doesn't support that method :(

Comment: Add a Watch for arrValues - what do you see?

Comment: @Absinthe I've never used it before but it says type is empty and value is out of context? my program doesn't break though so I'm not sure how watch will be useful

Comment: @beks a Watch will allow you to see what values the array holds, but of course you can only do that while the program is running and the array is in scope. Put a breakpoint on the End With after  arrValues = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)). Check the array to see if it holds the values you expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to copy unique value form 1 worksheet and copy them into several columns, spaced 4 columns apart, on another worksheet.  I achieve that here by adding unique values to dictionary as keys.  Next I loop over the columns counting by 4 `Step 4`, pasting the values in the second row.

[image]

```
Sub unique2()

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim arrUniqueValues, arrValues, k
    Dim wsRef As Worksheet
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet

    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wsRef = Worksheets("reference1")
    Set wsDB = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wsRef

        arrValues = .Range("F1", .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For Each k In arrValues

            If Len(k) And Not dict.Exists(k) Then dict.Add k, ""

        Next

    End With

    With wsDB

        For j = 6 To 24 Step 4

            .Cells(2, j).Resize(dict.Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)

        Next j

    End With

    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: the len(k) is giving me a type mismatch error - any idea why?

Comment: If you are using it on a variant array use k <> "" and cast the value into a string before using it as a key `dict.add CStr(k), ""`.